# What is the advised stack to work with Flink and Scala?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-flink

My current try:

- Eclipse 4.4.2 Luna with scala-ide plugin
- Rebuild Flink for scala 2.11 (by default maven downloads official Flink build which is for scala 2.10. This brings some issues with the IDE, such as the dreaded macros incompatibility

But working like that is somewhat cumbersome as you need :

- To rebuild Flink for scala 2.11 everytime you update to latest source
  code.
- have correct maven settings so that your project dependencies are not overwritten with Flink official build (i.e. overwriting your scala 2.11 Flink build with scala 2.10 build) when building your project in Eclipse.

Comment: Many people use Intellij IDEA. Eclipse has some problems with mixed-language project like Flink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running IntelliJ solved my issues.
I post this as an answer as Matthias provided the answer in a comment. Thanks Matthias.

Answer (score 1):

From Flink 0.10, the Flink community will provide Flink for Scala 2.11. Currently, you can use Flink for Scala 2.11 (0.10-SNAPSHOT) with [Apache Snapshot Maven Repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/flink/).

You can add the repository using following maven settings:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>apache.snapshots</id>
    <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```